# Netbeans debugger session: open in the same tab

Tags: php, debugging, firefox, netbeans, google-chrome

Running PHP debug session in Netbeans always opens as a new tab in browser (I use Chrome and Firefox).

How to force browser (or Netbeans) to run the session in the same browser tab,
so I do not have n open tabs with the same url for debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'ts really a browser issue, not a Netbeans issue. The browser command line provides no mechanism for using a particular tab. Generally, the only choice you have is whether or not to open a new instance of the browser.

I have worked around this in the past be adding a [meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) tag to periodically update the display.

Comment: Is not a browser choice, it's a Netbeans parameter

Comment: @Miguel Gil Martínez Yes, it is... 3 years later

Answer (score 5):

To prevent this go to

```
Project->Properties->Run Configuration->Advanced->Do not Open Web Browser
```